# Responsive design without framework or grid

Tags: web

I tried the fixed width method to successfully design a site, but I want it to fit all devices like even phone... I read about responsive design and got to know about the grid system and lots more but I came across an article and it seems they didnt use the grid system or frameworks. I want to make a responsive site without frameworks or using d grid system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries and viewport.